# Why does my browser display all-white (blank) text after installing some fonts?

Tags: 12.04, fonts

I installed a bunch of extra fonts for Ubuntu and now almost nothing involving fonts is displayed in my browser.

Comment: I know you aren't allowed to post pictures, but can you upload your image to imgur.com and just post the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Install MyUnity and reset your font settings . click here!  [MyUnity](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/myunity) and open it and select fonts in the menu. Reset all to its defaults and give a restart. look at the image [image]

source : [MyUnity](http://podzemski.com/2012/04/27/changing-the-default-font-size-on-ubuntu-12-04/)